# Android Animation skips frames

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to rotate some ImageViews (like [this](https://imgur.com/WoXbJ9S)), but some frames are skipped as shown [here](https://imgur.com/JtLQVnJ).

What I'm doing: I have a FrameLayout with 5 ImageViews.
I'm rotating them so that they form a pentagon.
Then, onClick(), I'm rotating them again on their X axis.
On this second animation, some frames are skipped.

Here's some code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        final int angle = i * 72;

        final ImageView image = setupImage(images.get(i), angle);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                image.setPivotY(0);
                image.animate().setDuration(5000).rotationX(180f);
            }
        });
    }
}

private ImageView setupImage(final ImageView image, float angle) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim =
            new RotateAnimation(0.0f, angle,
                                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
    rotateAnim.setDuration(1000);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    image.startAnimation(rotateAnim);

    return image;
}
```

I've also set `clipChildren = false` and `clipToPadding = false`

Answer (score 0):

Its because when activity does so many things on its main thread then it skips the frames.

one way to deal with it is to run your animation code in UI thread.

for example:

```
private void setupImage(){
 runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() {
         //your code here;
         }
     }
 }));
```

}

I also suggest you to check ur images size in the resource drawable file. Huge size may also leeds to skip the frames.

Comment: The `setupImage(...)` code is working as expected. I'll try to run the `onClick()` code in another thread

Comment: I suggest you to run the setUpImage() method in UiThread. I have been through this problem when I used Text Animation Library and solved problem in this way.

Comment: Tried that and still it skips some frames, but thanks :(